# How to make JFrame resize

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

My code is below:

```java
public class test extends JFrame {
    private void createGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        /* add some components */

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

And if I resize the window, it seems like:[image: Screenshot from 2019-09-30 13-54-40.png]

So how could make it resize with the window?

Comment: Set the fill constraint - for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923348/gridbaglayout-elements-behaviour-when-resizing-window/26923959#26923959)

Comment: You need to specify `GridBagConstraints.weightx` and/or`GridBagConstraints.weighty`. Both these parameters define which component takes the extra space. Also `GridBagConstraints.fill` could be helpfull, because the component does not get the extra space automatically.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can provide an assitance for your concrete case. Simply create a runnable example with your layout code, without any interactions.

Comment: Found the problem. I didn't set the weightx and weighty.